# Can I run Windows programs on Ubuntu + Virtual Box?

Tags: ubuntu, windows

I have Ubuntu on my computer. I was asked to do programming and spreadsheet by Visual Studio and Excel. Can I do this by installing Virtual Box from https://www.virtualbox.org/ , Windows 10, Visual Studio and Excel?

Comment: Yes - this is a common usage of Virtualbox on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes virtual box allows you to run an operating-system, and to then run programs on it.

Some use-cases such as 3D-cad or 3D-games or 3D-virtual reality, **may** be to much for the virtual machine. However if you have modern hardware (almost anything in the last 10 years), then any other use-case will be fine. It is even possible to have Microsoft's Windows run faster in Virtual-box than on real hardware.

Also consider other alternatives: Mono-develop it a .net development system. It is both **better and worse** than Visual Studio Professional (the most expensive one). However if your (or your customers) goal is to make a product that is incompatible with non-MS-Windows, then this may not be your best option.

Answer (score 1):

There's no logical reason why you can't install a Windows 10 guest OS in VirtualBox depending on the configuration of the guest's OS virtual hardware and what applications you install in it. Basically if the system requirements of the software that you plan to install on the guest OS are compatible with the resources allocated to the guest OS in the VirtualBox guest OS settings, the applications that are installed in the guest OS should run OK whatever they are.

In particular you need to allocate whatever virtual hardware resources to Visual Studio that it needs.